# Call on data from an unnamed nested dictionary on Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I've been working on Python for some time in University, but during my time in Uni we never used dictionaries, so I'm pretty new to this data type. I apologize if what I'm asking may have an obvious answer, but I've tried searching on google with no success. So basically I need to access data inside of a nested dictionary, but the nested dictionary:

1. Is inside a list.
2. Doesn't have an assigned name, neither does the dictionary that it is contained in have a name.

How would I go about accessing the data inside of this list?

So here is an example of what the nested dictionary structure looks like:

```
{
    "key1": value1,
    "key2": value2,
    "key3": [
        {
            "subkey1": subkey_value1,
            "subkey2": subkey_value2,
            "subkey3": subkey_value3
        }
    ]
},
{
    "key1": value1,
    "key2": value2,
    "key3": [
        {
            "subkey1": subkey_value1,
            "subkey2": subkey_value2,
            "subkey3": subkey_value3
        }
    ]
},
(etc.)
```

So I'm trying to access the data inside of one of the subkeys (say for example "subkey2") for multiple sets of similar structures. Could anyone please guide me on how I would go about approaching this?

Here is an example of how one of my attempted approaches to seeing if I can accessing the data, that seemed to get me the closest to what I need to get:

```
print(["key3"][0].get("subkey2"))
```

The json solution seems to have gotten me closer, but not quite there yet. So I basically said something along the lines of:

```
import requests 
url ="206.109.266.4:20000/announcements?$sort[createdAt]=-1" 
payload = {}
headers ={} 
response = requests.request("Get", url, headers=headers, data=payload) 
print(response.text) 
dic = response.text 
import json 
daysinfo = json.loads(dic) 
TripInfo = daysinfo["key3"][0] 
print(TripInfo["subkey3"]). –
```

"daysinfo" and "TripInfo" are printing as expected, but "print(TripInfo["subkey3"])" throws a KeyError issue

Comment: dic["key3"][0]["subkey2"]

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to have thrown up this error: "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: If you want to test this, build it up by first getting the value for key3, then the dictionary from the array in key3, and then access the dictionary key from that. You can do that by keep adding [] filled with some argument

Comment: I had attempted this earlier, and I managed to print the correct data from key3 and the list inside of it. It's just, once I get to the subkeys, I haven't been able to extract the data.

Comment: why not give the dict a name?

Comment: I'm calling it from an API request.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. In python you can only address data structures that have been assigned to a variable name or at least are several layers nested in something that has been assigned to a variable. So you would need to change your code so that at least at the highest level you have a variable name.

```
my_list = [
    {
        "key1": value1,
        "key2": value2,
        "key3": [
            {
                "subkey1": subkey_value1,
                "subkey2": subkey_value2,
                "subkey3": subkey_value3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key1": value1,
        "key2": value2,
        "key3": [
            {
                "subkey1": subkey_value1,
                "subkey2": subkey_value2,
                "subkey3": subkey_value3
            }
        ]
    }
]
print(my_list[0]["key3"][0]["subkey3"])
```

p.s. it might be that you are not looking at dictionary in a python list, but instead at a json object in a json array. In that case you might have to [load the file or the string in which your data structure resides with json](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp).

Comment: This seems to have gotten me closer, but nit quite there yet. So I basically said:

Comment: The json solution seems to have gotten me closer, but not quite there yet. So I basically said something along the lines of:                                                                                                    import requests

url = "http://206.109.266.4:20000/announcements?$sort[createdAt]=-1"

payload = {}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("Get", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)


dic = response.text 

import json
daysinfo = json.loads(dic)

TripInfo = daysinfo["key3"][0]

print(TripInfo["subkey3"]).

Comment: "daysinfo" and "TripInfo" are printing as expected, but "print(TripInfo["subkey3"])" throws a KeyError issue

Comment: Note that the requests library already has json build in. So you can just do `daysinfo = request.json()`. It is impossible to know why TripInfo["subkey3"] fails without knowing how TripInfo looks like. I think you can easily fix this yourself by just printing TripInfo and see what keys are in the TripInfo dict. The keyerror means you asked to retrieve the value of a nonexistent key.